# regular expression to replace &, but only inside a link

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that replaces ampersand characters (&) with double stars **, but ONLY if contained within an html HREF attribute (absolute or relative). Also, I need it to match the full `"&amp;"` string

So for example, the following HTML block:

```
<p>Ben & Jerry is <a href="http://www.domain.com?a=1&b=2&amp;c=3">cool</a></p>
<p>Ben & Jerry is <a href="/index.htm?a=1&b=2&amp;c=3">cool</a></p>
```

will become

```
<p>Ben & Jerry is <a href="http://www.domain.com?a=1**b=**c=3">cool</a></p>
<p>Ben & Jerry is <a href="/index.htm?a=1**b=2**c=3">cool</a></p>
```

I can replace all "&"s and all `"&amp;"`s, but am having problems containing it to within a link.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does it have to be using a regular expression?  It might be better to use an HTML parser.

Comment: I can imagine using Pattern and Matcher for <a href="(.*)", and then replace it in the string and use appendTail()

Comment: I'm afraid it does need to be a regular expression. This is actually going to be using a custom language of our content management system, in a very strange setup where HTML parsers can't be used. The only thing I have at my disposal is regular expressions.

Comment: `<a(.*)href=(.*)&(.*)>(.*)</a>` will match

Comment: That doesn't work Maciej Dobrowolski.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to only replace `&` if inside double-quoted text, regardless of whether an `href` attribute or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String html = "<p>Ben & Jerry is <a href=\"http://www.domain.com?a=1&b=2&amp;c"
            + "=3\">cool</a></p>\n<p>Ben & Jerry is <a href=\"/index.htm?a=1&b"
            + "=2&amp;c=3\">cool</a></p>";
String pattern = "(?i)" + // case insensitive modifier
            "(" + // open the capturing group 1
                "(?:" + // open a non capturing group
                    "<a\\s[^>]*?\\bhref\\s*=\\s*[\"']?" + // content until the href attribute value
                  "|" + // OR
                    "\\G(?<!^)" + // contiguous to a precedent match
                ")" + // close the non capturing group
                "[^\\s\"'&>]++" + // value content that is not a &
            ")" + // close the capturing group 1
            "&(?:amp;)?"; // & with optional "amp;"
String res = html.replaceAll(pattern, "$1**");
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Sorry, quite a delayed response here, I have been away. This worked like a charm, and I really appreciate the explanation.  Thanks for everything